# What is an XML Parser error out of allowed range and invalid element name?

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am getting this error in the log:

```
Entity: line 2: parser error : Char 0x0 out of allowed range
<
 ^
Entity: line 2: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
<
 ^
```

Here is the local code included in the iOS app bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nodes>
    <node>
        <type>spriteFile</type>
        <file>bones.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>250</x><y>50</y>
        </position>
        <scale>0.9</scale>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>spriteFile</type>
        <file>bones.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>100</x><y>200</y>
        </position>
        <scale>0.7</scale>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>spriteFile</type>
        <file>cart.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>270</x><y>45</y>
        </position>
        <scale>0.2</scale>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>spriteFile</type>
        <file>cart.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>100</x><y>90</y>
        </position>
        <scale>0.2</scale>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>spriteFile</type>
        <file>cart.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>360</x><y>200</y>
        </position>
        <scale>0.2</scale>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>texturedPolygon</type>
        <file>moon_texture.png</file>
        <position>
            <x>0</x><y>0</y>
        </position>
        <vertices>
            <vertex>
                <x>0</x><y>0</y>
            </vertex>
            <vertex>
                <x>480</x><y>0</y>
            </vertex>
            <vertex>
                <x>480</x><y>320</y>
            </vertex>
            <vertex>
                <x>0</x><y>320</y>
            </vertex>
        </vertices>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

Ok I converted it to plain text in textedit and here is the HexFile:
[image]

Comment: View the file in some Hex-editor. Perhaps it is UTF-16 and every second byte is zero.

Comment: Ok I did, what do I look for?  I have no idea what im looking at :)

Comment: What are the first hex bytes of the file?

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question with the screenshot of the hex file.

Answer (score 1):

That is a RTF document. You have to save the XML as plain text file.

Comment: Ok, I converted it to plain text and re-uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: @marciokoko: That looks better, but it is not UTF-16. You should switch your Hex viewer to "ISO 8859-1" or "ISO Latin" or similar, so that you see the contents correctly. Do you still get exactly the same error message with the new file?

Comment: Guess what, I removed the encoding="ISO-8859-1" tag from the xml and it works :)  Why is that?

Comment: @marciokoko: I cannot tell you without having the file and inspecting it, but without an encoding tag the XML library determines the encoding depending on the first bytes.